# React Native how to use an external style sheet file

Tags: react-native

I couldn't find the current method for achieving this. It used to be:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var { StyleSheet } = React;

module.exports = StyleSheet.create({

});
```

In a separate file and then you would require it as follows:

`var styles = require('./styles');`

But that no longer seems to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in styles.js file, you can do

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
});

export default styles;
```

and in other files

```
import styles from './styles';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the following:

**Style.js**

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'; 

export default Style = StyleSheet.create({
    // your styles here 
    container: {
       flex: 1 
    }
});
```

And then you import your StyleSheet with:

```
import Style from 'PATH_TO_STYLE.js';
```

and then you can use it with:

```
<View style={Style.container} />
```